# Derive steepest descent vector subject to norm constraint

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I am currently working through an old textbook Practical Optimization by Gill, Murray and Wright (c 1982) who make some derivations which seem correct, but I am unable to duplicate.  In the equations below $g$ and $p$ are both vectors. $g$ is the gradient from the current iterate of a optimization procedure and $p$ is the search direction we wish to solve for.

The authors inform the reader that the minimum (over $p$) of

$\Large\frac{g'p}{||p||}$ is $p=-g$.

Alternatively, we might form a different norm for $p$ by considering a symmetric positive definite matrix $C$ in which case the minimizer of

$\Large\frac{g'p}{(p'Cp)^{1/2}}$ 
is 
$p=-C^{-1}g$.

I am having trouble deriving these statements.

**My question is**: Does it take more than a derivative and setting equal to zero to prove this?  If so, how do I derive these formulas?

This question is similar to

[Gradient descent with constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54855/gradient-descent-with-constraints)

but not identical. This other question deals with solutions that are unit length, not necessarily step directions which are unit length.

Comment: Note that if $p$ is a minimizer in the above problems, then so is $\lambda p$, where $\lambda >0$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz.

$(g^Tp)^2 \leq \|g\|^2 \|p\|^2.$

So, $-\|g\| \leq \frac{g^T p}{\|p\|} \leq \|g\| $ and the lower bound is attained when $ p = -g $.

Similarly,
$ (g^T p)^2 = \langle C^{-1/2}g , C^{1/2} p\rangle^2 \leq (g^T C^{-1} g) \times (p^T C p) $ and the lower bound is similarly attained.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to look at the problem (which ends up being equivalent) of solving $\min \{ \langle g, h \rangle | \|h\| \leq 1 \}$. The norm is the standard $2$-norm. The reason I prefer this formulation is that it is closer in form to the original problem from which the search direction problem is derived. Also, it has a trust region flavor, which I personally find more appealing than a search direction/step length approach.

For the first problem, the Cauchy Bunyakovsky Schwarz Beiber inequality gives $|\langle g, h \rangle| \leq \|g\| \|h\|$, hence it is easy to see that the minimum is 
$\min \{ \langle g, h \rangle \,|\, \|h\| \leq 1 \} = - \|g\|$, and the minimizer is (it is unique with the $2$-norm) $h = -\frac{1}{\|g\|} g$. You could also derive this by noting that (if $g\neq 0$), the constraint $\|h\| \leq 1$ must be active, and use Lagrange multipliers to obtain the same result.

For the second, let $A^TA = C$ be the Cholesky decomposition of $C$. The problem is now $\min \{ \langle g, h \rangle \,|\, \|Ah\| \leq 1 \} = \min \{ \langle g, h \rangle \,|\, \|\delta\| \leq 1, \, h= A^{-1}\delta \} $. This is equivalent to $\min \{ \langle g, A^{-1}\delta \rangle \,|\, \|\delta\| \leq 1 \} = \min \{ \langle (A^{-1})^T g, \delta \rangle \,|\, \|\delta\| \leq 1 \}$, where $h = A^{-1}\delta$, and the first problem shows that the minimum is $-\|(A^{-1})^T g\|$ and the minimizer is $\delta = -\frac{1}{\|(A^{-1})^T g\|} (A^{-1})^Tg$, or in terms of the original problem $h = A^{-1}\delta = -\frac{1}{\|(A^{-1})^T g\|} A^{-1}(A^{-1})^Tg$. Since $A^TA = C$, we have $\|(A^{-1})^T g\| = \sqrt{\langle (A^{-1})^T g, (A^{-1})^T g \rangle} = \sqrt{\langle  g, C^{-1} g \rangle}$, and $h = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle  g, C^{-1} g \rangle}} C^{-1} g$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha} \def\g{\gamma} \def\b{\beta}
\def\o{{\tt1}} \def\t{\theta} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\C{C^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The first function is a special case of the second, so we only need to examine the function
$$\eqalign{
\phi(p) &= \frac{g^Tp}{\sqrt{p^TCp}} \\
}$$
Note that if $p$ is replaced by $\l p$, the value of the function is unchanged: $\;\phi(\l p)=\phi(p)$

Consider the numerator and denominator as separate functions
$\LR{{\rm i.e.}\;\;\phi = \large{\frac\a\b}}$
$$\eqalign{
\a &= g^Tp &\qiq &d\a = g^Tdp \\
\b^2 &= p^TCp &\qiq &2\b\:d\b = 2\LR{Cp}^T\:dp \qiq d\b= \fracLR{Cp}{\b}^Tdp }$$
Then use the quotient rule to calculate the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \fracLR{\b\:d\a - \a\:d\b}{\b^2} \\
 &= \fracLR{\o}{\b}g^Tdp - \fracLR{\a}{\b^3}\LR{Cp}^Tdp \\
\grad{\phi}{p}
 &= \fracLR{\o}{\b}g - \fracLR{\a}{\b^3} {Cp} \\
}$$
Setting this gradient to zero determines the optimal $p,\,$
up to a scale factor
$$\eqalign{
g &= \fracLR{\a}{\b^2} {Cp} \qiq p = \l \C g  \\
}$$
We don't care about the magnitude of $\l$ but we do care about its **sign**

since we require $p$ to be a **descent** direction
$$g^Tp=\a\lt0 \qiq \l=-\o$$