# How to map a higher dimensional vector to a lower dimensional subspace that satisfies multiple constraints?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, gradient-descent, constraints

I'd like to perform constrained gradient descent in a high-dimensional space. I'm planning to compute the gradient in the high-dimensional space and then project it to a lower-dimensional space that satisfies multiple constraints. I don't know how to mathematically express that lower-dimensional subspace, or how to project a higher dimensional vector onto it.

The objective is to have a matrix of $\gamma$ values that are as close to one as possible.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_a & \gamma_b \\
\gamma_c & \gamma_d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The $\gamma$ values are non-negative weights that are multiplied by non-negative $n$ values. The constraints act upon the products of the $\gamma$ and $n$ values.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_a & \gamma_b \\
\gamma_c & \gamma_d
\end{bmatrix}
\odot
\begin{bmatrix}
n_a & n_b \\
n_c & n_d
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_a n_a & \gamma_b n_b \\
\gamma_c n_c & \gamma_d n_d
\end{bmatrix}  =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The constraints are that the rows and columns of the $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$
matrix sum to the same values:

$$ a + b = c + d $$
$$ a + c = b + d $$

Since $\gamma$ is a weight I'd like the objective function to score $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ equivalently (and $3$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ equivalently) as if they're 'equally far from 1'. I've come up with the following objective function to optimize:
$$ f = \sum_{i}^{a, b, c, d} \log(\gamma_i)^2 $$

Let's say - for example's sake - that the values of $n$ are as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n_a & n_b \\
n_c & n_d
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 60 \\
99 & 40
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I figure out the optimal values for $
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_a & \gamma_b \\
\gamma_c & \gamma_d
\end{bmatrix}
$?

---

I've tried using Lagrange multipliers for this, but it requires me to solve a system of equations with logarithms and reciprocals in it, which breaks my automatic equation solver `sympy`. I'm looking to extend this idea to many dimensions, so I *have* to have an automatic solver to solve the system of equations, solving by hand is not an option. `sympy` throws a `NotImplementedError` when solving the system of equations for me.

The derivative of the objective function is:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma_i} = 2 \log(\gamma_i)\frac{1}{\gamma_i} $$

I'm also fine with redifining the objective function (so long as $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ receive equal score):

$$ f = \sum_{i}^{a, b, c, d} (1 -\gamma_i)^2 + (1 - \frac{1}{\gamma_i})^2  $$

But this didn't help me with the Lagrange Multiplier approach.

---

Back to constrained gradient descent. I'm guessing that this is a convex problem, which would mean that gradient descent would converge to the global optimum.

I got the idea of constrained gradient descent from this post:
[Gradient descent with constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54855/gradient-descent-with-constraints)

The idea is to project the high-dimensional gradient to the subspace that meets the constraints. In their case the projection is onto a sphere, which can be performed as normalizing the vector norm.

Their solution doesn't fit my needs, because I don't know how to formulate and perform the projection to a lower dimensional space that satisfies the constraints.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question; I found a useful reference on p367 of this book: https://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf.

The constraints should be written in $Ax = b$ format:
$$
n_a \gamma_a + n_b \gamma_b - n_c \gamma_c - n_d \gamma_d = 0
$$
$$
n_a \gamma_a - n_b \gamma_b + n_c \gamma_c - n_d \gamma_d = 0
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
n_a &  n_b & -n_c & -n_d \\
n_a & -n_b &  n_c & -n_d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_a \\ \gamma_b \\ \gamma_c \\ \gamma_d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The projection matrix that projects a vector onto the subspace is then:
$$
P = I - A^T (A A^T)^{-1}A 
$$

Constrained gradient descent can then be performed by computing the gradient of the objective function for a set of gamma values, projecting the gradient to the subspace by multiplying it with the matrix $P$ and applying the gradient. It is important to start with an initial $\gamma_0$ that is already on the subspace. I went with:
$$ 
\vec{\gamma_0} 
= 
\frac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{n_a} \\ \frac{1}{n_b} \\ \frac{1}{n_c} \\ \frac{1}{n_d}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
50 \\ 0.833 \\ 0.505 \\ 1.25
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I also found it helpful to add the constraint

$$ a + b + c + d = 1 $$

And to use the objective function

$$ f = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N (1 - \gamma_i)^2 + (1 - \frac{1}{\gamma_i})^2 $$

instead of the $\log$ based one (because the quadratic one punishes outliers more).

Hope this helps someone out there!